# recentemente instalei o magento no localhost via wampserver e deu um erro no index oq eu faço?

Tags: magento

quando eu entrei na plataforma magento apareceu uma mensagem e quando eu abri apareceu isso[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

oque eu faço para reindexar esses arquivos

Comment: Aparentemente parece um erro de relacionamento de bases, tenta instalar denovo.

Answer (score 0):

Só para constar..
Para "reindexar" os dados no Magento 2 e retirar essa mensagem do Backend deverá ser configurado as rotinas de serviços via "cron" ou executado comando manualmente via CLI.
Infelizmente no WAMP/XAMP/etc que rodam no Window será muito difícil de realizar esse processo ou executar via comando "bin/magento", além do fato do Magento 2 não ser oficialmente compatível com sistema operacional Windows.